# Change of content within a div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking into ways of changing the content within a div based on a specific button.

Basically I have this:

[Latest Match Div](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PqrIl.png)

By default, the contents of the "National League" will show up, so when I click on "MHA Cup", the content will change to games that are "MHA CUP" related and as well as "Friendlies".

How can something like this be done?

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 75px auto;
}

.parent h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.category {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.category li {
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #01296f;
}

.category li,
.show-all li {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.match {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}

.match-details {
  text-align: center;
}

#friendlies {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#mha-cup {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.home-team,
.away-team {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.team-badge {
  background: grey;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 30px;
}

.team-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: -10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.match-type{
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #999999;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.match-score span{
  background: #01296f;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7.5px 10px;
}

.match-status{
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <h1>Latest Matches</h1>
      <ul>
        <div class="category">
          <li>National League</li>
          <li>MHA Cup</li>
          <li>Friendlies</li>
        </div>
        <div class="show-all">
          <li>Show All</li>
        </div>
      </ul>

      <div class="tables" id="national-league">
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>MHA CUP - SEMIFINALS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>  
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
                FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>MHA CUP - SEMIFINALS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>  
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
                FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: use `TextContent` to change the text with js https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/textContent, can you explain more what you need and what is the problem

Comment: Use Bootstrap tabs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/navs-tabs/

Answer (score 0):

Not the most efficient but an easy way to do this without having to add Bootstrap/JQuery is to use JavaScript to add/remove "display: none;" style to the content you want to show and hide and set the button as the trigger to alternate between the two.

Answer (score 0):

you can just give put display none to each div you want to hide with javascript is quite easy actually.

here is how you do it

```js
let ids = ['friendlies', 'national-league', 'mha-cup']

function show(tab) {
  ids.forEach((id) => {
    document.getElementById(id).style = 'display: none'
  });
  document.getElementById(tab).style = 'display: block';
}

function showAll() {
  ids.forEach((id) => {
    document.getElementById(id).style = 'display: block'
  });
}
```

```css
@import url("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Raleway:wght@100;200;300;400;500;600;700;800;900&display=swap");

* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
}

body {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  width: 100vw;
}

ul,
li {
  list-style: none;
}

.parent {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 60%;
  margin: 75px auto;
}

.parent h1 {
  font-weight: 900;
  font-size: 16px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.parent ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.category {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.category li {
  margin-right: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 5px;
  margin-bottom: 50px;
  border-bottom: 2.5px solid #01296f;
}

.category li,
.show-all li {
  font-size: 12px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-weight: 600;
}

.match {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background: white;
  align-items: center;
  height: 120px;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #F0F0F0;
}

.match-details {
  text-align: center;
}

#friendlies {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#mha-cup {
  border: 2px solid purple;
}

.home-team,
.away-team {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.team-badge {
  background: grey;
  height: 42px;
  width: 42px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  margin: 30px;
}

.team-name {
  font-weight: 700;
  padding: -10px;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  font-size: 12px;
}

.match-type {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  color: #999999;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}

.match-score span {
  background: #01296f;
  color: white;
  border-radius: 5px;
  padding: 7.5px 10px;
}

.match-status {
  margin: 20px;
  font-size: 10px;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css" />
    <title>Static Template</title>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="parent">
      <h1>Latest Matches</h1>
      <ul>
        <div class="category">
          <li><button onClick="show('national-league');">National League</button></li>
          <li><button onClick="show('mha-cup');">
              MHA Cup
            </button></li>
          <li><button onClick="show('friendlies');">
              Friendlies
            </button></li>
        </div>
        <div class="show-all">
          <li><button onClick="showAll();">
              Show All
            </button></li>
        </div>
      </ul>

      <div class="tables" id="mha-cup">
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>MHA CUP - SEMIFINALS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
              FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>MHA CUP - SEMIFINALS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
              FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tables" id="national-league">
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>National League</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
              FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>MHA CUP - SEMIFINALS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
              FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="tables" id="friendlies">
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>Friendlies</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
              FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="match">
          <div class="home-team">
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
            <span class="team-name">La Salle</span>
          </div>
          <div class="match-details">
            <div class="match-type">
              <h4>MHA CUP - SEMIFINALS</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="match-score">
              <span>25 - 24</span>
            </div>
            <div class="match-status">
              FULL TIME
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="away-team">
            <span class="team-name">HMS</span>
            <div class="team-badge"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>
  </body>

</html>
```